# Validate a date from has_many-belongs_to relation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, model

I having the problem a of validate a date in a relation has_many/belong_to.
I'm making a Netflix web to learn Rails and I want to validate the expire date of an episode is not after the expire date of the serie which belongs to that episode.

I tried to do something like this (I'm using date-validator gem):

A serie (name) has many episodes and an episode (name, serie_id) belongs to a serie, this is my code form now:

```
class Episode < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :serie
    #validates :expire_date, date: { before: Serie.find(:serie_id).expire_date } #This line explodes, that's what I want to fix
end

class Serie < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :episodes, dependent: :destroy
}
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just write your own [validation method](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods):

```
class Episode < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :serie

  validate :validate_expiry_date, 
    unless: ->{ serie.nil? } #  # this prevents a potential nil error

  private

  def validate_expiry_date
    if self.expire_date > self.serie.expiry_date
      errors.add(:expire_date, 'some sort of descriptive error message')
    end
  end
end
```

No gems needed.

A validation is just a method that tests a predicate and adds a error to the errors object it the validation fails.

Comment: Thanks, that worked very well, I just added ```!(self.serie.expire_date).nil?``` to the conditional statment to check if the serie doesn't has an expire_date.